Efficiently mark and retrieve rows
I'm working on a SQL Server query where I need to perform the following tasks efficiently:

Execute a complex and resource-intensive SELECT statement to retrieve a subset of rows.
Update same table using the IDs from this select operation.
Return the same set of rows without recalculating the select query.

Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve:
;WITH ExpensiveCTE AS 
(
    -- Expensive and complex query
    SELECT TOP 1000 id, other_columns
    FROM my_table
    WHERE complex_conditions
    ORDER BY some_expensive_sorting
)
-- Update operation based on the CTE results
UPDATE my_table
SET columnA = 1
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM ExpensiveCTE)

-- Retrieve the same set of data
SELECT *
FROM ExpensiveCTE

The SELECT query is very heavy, and recalculating it is too slow. I attempted to use a table variable to store the results, but this approach has made the query three times slower.
Microsoft SQL Server does not let me use the CTE twice (both in Select and Update).
What strategies or SQL Server features can I use to improve efficiency for these operations?
Edit: I attempted to optimize my SQL operations by extracting just the ids from my_table and storing them in a table variable with the following steps:
DECLARE @Ids TABLE (id INT); 

INSERT INTO @Ids (id) 
    SELECT id
    FROM my_table 
    WHERE complex_conditions; 

UPDATE my_table 
SET columnA = 1 
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM @Ids);

SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
INNER JOIN @Ids ON my_table.id = @Ids.id
INNER JOIN other_complex_joins

However, I'm facing performance issues with this approach.
Edit-2: The part I'm struggling with is that when I first used SELECT, it was quite efficient, taking only 1-2 seconds. However, once the requirement arose to update a column to indicate that the selected rows are in process, I opted to use a table variable. The only change I made was an INSERT INTO @tableVariable,then SELECT * FROM @tableVariable(I will add an UPDATE in between once I resolve the performance issue)
Execution plan showed that while the insertion into the @tableVariable only account for a small operator cost (3%), the overall execution plan was affected significantly.

(1) you could have a BIT flag in the rows, and just mark those rows of interest in the first pass, then do your other steps; or (2) you could extract just the primary key from the rows of interest into a temp table or table variable, and then use that to join for your subsequent operations

Table Variables in SQL Server result in poor cardinality estimations, which may be the cause of your negative performance change.
How is your performance changed by using a Temporary Table in place of the table variable?
The IN predicate used in your update should be reconsidered as an INNER JOIN or an EXISTS - IN tends to cause serial behavior, which has negative performance implications

use output clause? update t set something = other output inserted.* from yourtable t

@marc_s Thank you for the suggestion. But
(1)I first extracted the id of the intended rows into a table variable.
(2)I then inner join between the table variable and the main table to update the rows.
(3)Finally, I did an inner join with the main table using the extracted ids for my SELECT operation.
However, I noticed that the execution time increased significantly from around 6-7 seconds to 40 seconds. It seems like the table variable may be causing this slowdown when joining with the real table. Do you have any tips on how to optimize this approach?

@siggemannen Thank you for the suggestion! The OUTPUT clause is indeed powerful, but I'm encountering a specific challenge with it. My initial SELECT involves several joins and calculations across multiple tables. When using the OUTPUT clause in the UPDATE statement, it only returns the columns from the updated table, not the complete set of data produced by the original SELECT which spans multiple tables.
Is there a way to capture the entire result set from my complex query while updating a single table, or would I need a different approach? Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Ok, then i'd probably save the select to a temp table first and then update the main table by using a simple join on IDs. You might be able to access some of the unrelated columns by doing a merged update, but i'm now getting the feeling you're doing something wrong, so i don't want to add even more wrongness to it :)

Following your edits, you appear to still be using a table variable (@) and getting poor performance from it. Please try using a temp table (#) in place of the table variable to see if there is a difference in performance

You can use the OUTPUT clause for this.
And you don't need to join the CTE, you can update it directly.
WITH ExpensiveCTE AS 
(
    -- Expensive and complex query
    SELECT TOP (1000) t.*
    FROM my_table t
    WHERE complex_conditions
    ORDER BY some_expensive_sorting
)
-- Update operation based on the CTE results
UPDATE ExpensiveCTE
SET columnA = 1
OUTPUT inserted.*;


Thank you for your suggestion, but I encountered a couple of issues with the approach
In my case, I need to ensure the original table is updated, not a temporary view of it. Do you have any other suggestions that could align with these requirements? Thank you for your help!

Objective Clarification: My goal isn't to update the CTE itself but to update the base table (my_table) based on the results from the CTE. I plan to temporarily mark the selected rows by updating columnA to 1, so that other transactions do not select these rows until I set it back to 0 in a subsequent transaction.
SQL Server Limitation: SQL Server does not allow direct updates to CTEs because they are not a physical construct like a table or view but rather a temporary, logical query result. The update operation needs to occur on the base table, not the logical dataset produced by the CTE.

"SQL Server Limitation: SQL Server does not allow direct updates to CTEs because they are not a physical construct like a table or view but rather a temporary, logical query result" this is not true. SQL Server can write through a view or CTE to the base table as long as it conforms to certain constructs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#updatable-views So basically as long as there is no GROUP BY or DISTINCT and the columns you are updating are passed through without any calculation you should be OK.

In my case, the SELECT statement is designed to collect data from multiple tables through complex joins and calculations. However, I update only one table. When attempting to return the full result set using the OUTPUT clause, I encountered an error:
“The column reference "inserted.ColumnC" is not allowed because it refers to a base table that is not being modified in this statement.”

OK you'd have to show that in your question. There are some bugs around window functions see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/326842/output-clause-with-window-functions, also you can only output the base table columns with UPDATE

"The column reference "inserted.ColumnC" is not allowed because it refers to a base table that is not being modified in this statement."
To work around that issue, use MERGE instead of UPDATE.  MERGE doesn't have this limitation.

It will be much more efficient if you do:
DECLARE @Ids TABLE (id INT); 

CREATE TABLE #T (ID INT PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO #T
SELECT id
FROM   my_table 
WHERE  complex_conditions; 

UPDATE my_table 
SET    columnA = 1 
WHERE  id IN (SELECT id FROM #T);

SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
INNER JOIN #T ON my_table.id = #T.id
INNER JOIN other_complex_joins

